# Joining CSV and shapefile to map using R?

Tags: r

I have one CSV file and one shapefile

```
mydata <-readr::read_csv("~/map/done.csv")
mymap <- shapefile("~/map/tyumen.shp")
```

How merge it to one table and draw plot?

```
map_and_data <- merge(mydata, mymap, by='Country')


ggplot(map_and_data) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=MeDianIncome))

ggplot(map_and_data)+ 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = MedianIncome))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low= "#56B1F7", high = "#132B43")
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `*_join` from *dplyr* package, for instance:

```
map_and_data <- dplyr::left_join(mymap, mydata, by='Country')
```

Here is one example you can test.

```
library(sf)
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
my_table = data.frame(NAME= nc$NAME, INCOME= runif(100, 5000, 10000))

library(dplyr)
merged = left_join(nc, my_table, by= "NAME")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(merged)+
    geom_sf(aes(fill= INCOME))+
    scale_fill_gradient(low= "#56B1F7", high = "#132B43")
```

[image]

Comment: how use my path for fie?

Comment: nc = st_read(system.file("~/map/tyumen.shp", package="sf")) this code not working

Comment: @user1088259 use `st_read("~/map/tyumen.shp")`, @Kazuhito used an example file to show you how to use this function